# SUA-Korn shell not retaining environment variables

Tags: ksh, sua

I am using SUA-Korn shell on Windows where in I have set an alias in .profile as alias sqlplus='sqlplus.exe'

So when I start SUA-Korn shell and run sqlplus it calls sqlplus.exe and works fine but when I put same command in .ksh file and run it gives error that 'unknown command sqlplus'

Below is .ksh file

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus main/main@SID9 @script.sql
```

If I execute above test.ksh in SUA-Korn shell as

```
. test.ksh
```

then it works fine but

```
test.ksh
```

gives

> unknown command sqlplus.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, aliases only work in interactive shells.  I would suggest using a function or a variable instead.  Both of these will translate to your shell script.

In your **.profile:**

```
sqlplus="sqlplus.exe"
```

In your **script**:

```
eval $sqlplus main/main@SID9 @script.sql
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: is this a limit of ksh, or the SUA environment in general